# clusterExport, environment and variable scoping

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I wrote a function in which I define variables and load objects. Here's a simplified version:

```
fn1 <- function(x) {
  load("data.RData") # a vector named "data"
  source("myFunctions.R")
  library(raster)
  library(rgdal)

  a <- 1
  b <- 2
  r1 <- raster(ncol = 10, nrow = 10)
  r1 <- init(r1, fun = runif)
  r2 <- r1 * 100
  names(r1) <- "raster1"
  names(r2) <- "raster2"
  m <- stack(r1, r2) # basically, a list of two rasters in which it is possible to access a raster by its name, like this: m[["raster1"]]

  c <- fn2(m)
}
```

Function "fn2" is can be found in "myFunctions.R" and is defined as:

```
fn2 <- function(x) {
  fn3 <- function(y) {
   x[[y]] * 100 * data
  }

  cl <- makeSOCKcluster(8)   
  clusterExport(cl, list("x"), envir = environment()) 
  clusterExport(cl, list("a", "b", "data")) 
  clusterEvalQ(cl, c(library(raster), library(rgdal), rasterOptions(maxmemory = a, chunksize = b))) 
  f <- parLapply(cl, names(x), fn3)  
  stopCluster(cl)
}
```

Now, when I run fn1, I get an error like this:

```
Error in get(name, envir = envir) : object 'a' not found
```

From what I understand from ?clusterExport, the default value for envir is .GlobalEnv, so I would assume that "a" and "b" would be accessible to fn2. However, it doesn't seem to be the case. How can I access the environment to which "a" and "b" belong?

So far, the only solution I have found is to pass "a" and "b" as arguments to fn2. Is there a way to use these two variables in fn2 without passing them as arguments?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting the error when calling `clusterExport(cl, list("a", "b", "data"))` because `clusterExport` is trying to find the variables in `.GlobalEnv`, but `fn1` isn't setting them in `.GlobalEnv` but in its own local environment.

An alternative is to pass the local environment of `fn1` to `fn2`, and specify that environment to `clusterExport`. The call to `fn2` would be:

```
c <- fn2(m, environment())
```

If the arguments to `fn2` are `function(x, env)`, then the call to `clusterExport` would be:

```
clusterExport(cl, list("a", "b", "data"), envir = env)
```

Since environments are passed by reference, there should be no performance problem doing this.

Comment: Thanks for making this clearer, @Steve Weston. I agree with you its a bit messy. I gave it more thinking and I can load the data within the function where it is used. As for the cluster calls, I will make the cluster object (cl) and call clusterEvalQ from my main function, fn1, and then I will pass cl as an argument to functions that need to do some clusterExport() before calling parallel functions like parLapply.